# Laravel 5.2 redirect back after login

Tags: php, laravel

I used php artisan `make:auth`.

How can I change `protected $redirectTo = '/';` in `AuthController` If I want redirect back not `/`?

Please give some tips in detail.(file name …)

Answer (score 1):

To redirect after login, goto **app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php** and change the `protected $redirectTo = '/home';` to `protected $redirectTo = '/your-custom-url';`

You can also change the redirect after register for this goto **app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php** and change the **$redirectTo** property.

Comment: I already know protected $redirectTo = 'any-url'; in app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php. I want to redirect before page not 'any-url'

Comment: This is managed by laravel automatically, if you protect any route with 'auth' middleware.

Answer (score 1):

In `app\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController.php`

There is a variable Named `$redirectTo`
Here you can change the path to redirect after login

Comment: I already know protected $redirectTo = 'any-url'; in app\Http\Controllers\Auth\AuthController.php. I want to redirect before page not 'any-url'

Answer (score 0):

Though I haven't tried it yet but you should be able do that by overriding the `redirectPath` method of `RedirectsUsers` traits in your `AuthController` as follows

```
  /**
 * Get the post register / login redirect path.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function redirectPath()
{
    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: sry for checking yours  lately, Can I ask some questions?